# Cannot start service created with Apache Daemon on Windows Server - Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2, windows-server-2012-r2, apache-commons-daemon

I'm facing some trouble while trying to start a windows service that I've created with [Apache Daemon](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-daemon/) on an Amazon EC2 Instance (Windows Server 2012 R2). The error I'm getting is "Windows could not start the service_name on local Computer. For more information, review the System Event Log. If this is a non-Microsoft service, contact the service vendor, and refer to service-specific error code 1."

I checked some other links and most of the similar problems are related to Apache servers issues, but I already have Apache Tomcat working perfectly here and the problem seems to be related to the windows service only.

Does anyone have any idea?